# DllImport ERROR_MORE_DATA UNMANAGED Call C++ in C#

Tags: c#, winapi, registry, unmanaged, dllimport

```
   DWORD OREnumKey(
      __in         ORHKEY Handle,
      __in         DWORD dwIndex,
      __out        PWSTR lpName,
      __inout      PDWORD lpcName,
      __out_opt    PWSTR lpClass,
      __inout_opt  PDWORD lpcClass,
      __out_opt    PFILETIME lpftLastWriteTime
    );
```

My code

```
[DllImport("offreg.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern uint OREnumKey(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr dwIndex, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]out StringBuilder lpName, ref IntPtr lpcName, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]out StringBuilder lpClass, ref IntPtr lpcClass, out System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME lpftLastWriteTime);
 IntPtr myKey = hiveid;
    IntPtr dwindex=(IntPtr)0;
    StringBuilder lpName=new StringBuilder("",255);
    IntPtr lpcName = (IntPtr)0;
    StringBuilder  lpClass=new StringBuilder("",255);
    IntPtr lpcClass = (IntPtr)11;
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME lpftLastWriteTime;
    uint ret3 = OREnumKey(myKey, dwindex, out lpName, ref lpcName, out lpClass, ref lpcClass, out lpftLastWriteTime);
```

ret3=ERROR_MORE_DATA 234
Problem can be in wrong StringBuilder Size, or FILETIME
2nd How i should call   PWSTR param from C#?
`[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]out StringBuilder lpName` is it correct?

Comment: does this give you a better signature? http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/14120

Comment: I already saw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624373/error-more-data-pvoid-and-c-sharp-unmanaged-types   But there are PVOID, in my sample looks like problem in PWSTR

Comment: i just tried clrinterop.codeplex.com and used their signature/ The same error, looks like it is microsoft bug

Comment: And what's the issue? It's reporting that the value is too long to fit in the buffer you've passed in. As your passing 0 for the length it says it's too small and changes lpcName to the value required.

Comment: You may also try adding some punctuation to the description you've given, it barely makes sense, and I'm guessing what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty standard Windows error code, it means that you called a winapi function and you didn't pass a big enough buffer.  The only way to fix the problem is to pass a bigger buffer.

This looks a lot like a wrapper for RegQueryKeyEx(), which makes it very likely that you are passing bad data to the function.  The *lpcName* argument is actually `ref int`, not IntPtr.  And you are supposed to pass a variable that stores the size of the buffer you passed, 255 in your case.  The lpcClass argument is similarly borked.  This ought to fix it:

```
[DllImport("offreg.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern uint OREnumKey(
    IntPtr Handle, 
    int dwIndex,
    StringBuilder lpName, 
    ref int lpcName, 
    StringBuilder lpClass, 
    ref int lpcClass, 
    out System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME lpftLastWriteTime);

    ...   
    StringBuilder lpName=new StringBuilder("",255);
    int nameSize = lpName.Capacity;
    StringBuilder  lpClass=new StringBuilder("",255);
    int classSize = lpClass.Capacity;
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME lpftLastWriteTime;
    uint ret3 = OREnumKey(hiveid, 0, lpName, ref nameSize, lpClass, ref classSize, out lpftLastWriteTime);
    if (ret3 != 0) throw new Exception("kaboom");
    string name = lpName.ToString();
    string className = lpClass.ToString();
```